# php query for iOS latitude and longitude not searching for nearby mysql lat and lon with a xml output

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am trying to get the output of the lat and lon coordinates from ios (this is working fine), send it to php to query with MySQL and have the php emit an xml document back to ios(this step is not working because it is refusing to read an uploaded data entry from mysql), then parsing it on iOS UItableview (this is working fine too). I am trying to get this to work with XML because parsing xml on iOS is really simple for me and I've gotten a simpler xml script running already on it, but probably due to mistakes from inexperience in php, I cannot get this php script working. What am I doing wrong in my php script? Thanks!

```
<?php
{ $lat = (float)$_GET['lat']; } //ios get "lat" value from: NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/loc.php?lat=%g&lon=%g", latitude, longitude];
{ $lon = (float)$_GET['lon']; } //ios get "lon" value from: NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/loc.php?lat=%g&lon=%g", latitude, longitude];
$minlat = $lat-.1;
$maxlat = $lat+.1;
$minlon = $lon-.1;
$maxlon = $lon+.1;
$dbh = new PDO('(censored personal information)');
$sql = 'SELECT lat, lon, name FROM locations WHERE lat >= ? AND lat <= ? AND lon >= ? AND lon <= ?';
$params = array( $minlat, $maxlat, $minlon, $maxlon );
$q = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$q->execute( $params );
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$r = $doc->createElement( "locations" );
$doc->appendChild( $r );
foreach ( $q->fetchAll() as $row) {
  {
    $e = $doc->createElement( "location" );
    $e->setAttribute( 'name', $row['name'] );
    $e->setAttribute( 'd', $d );
    $r->appendChild( $e );
  }
}
print $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: Ah. Forgot to delete that. Thanks. But still doesn't fix it

Comment: What output do you receive?  Are there any errors?  How does the XML differ from your expectation?  Try visiting the webpage in a browser with appropriate GET parameters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue with php not matching lon and lat from ios with a mysql data entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870967/issue-with-php-not-matching-lon-and-lat-from-ios-with-a-mysql-data-entry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're new to PHP, I thought I'd record my observations on your script by walking through it line-by-line:

```
{ $lat = (float)$_GET['lat']; }
{ $lon = (float)$_GET['lon']; }
```

The braces here are superfluous.  You might also wish to perform some input sanity checks (including whether the parameters were set at all).

```
$minlat = $lat-.1;
$maxlat = $lat+.1;
$minlon = $lon-.1;
$maxlon = $lon+.1;
```

If you're looking to search for records within some range on the ground, you will want to calculate [great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance); you should be aware that, with your current approach, the distance of 0.1° longitude varies with one's latitude, from no distance whatsoever at the poles to almost 7 miles at the equator.

Google have written a useful guide under [Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3): pay particular attention to the section on [Finding Locations with MySQL](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#findnearsql) and (in your case) [Outputting XML with PHP](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#outputxml).

Place the rest of the code in one or more `try { ... }` blocks and catch any exceptions thrown.

```
$dbh = new PDO('(censored personal information)');
```

Check that it succeeded: `if (!$dbh) die('Unable to create PDO object');`.

Then set this PDO object to raise exceptions `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` and not merely to emulate prepared statements `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);`.

```
$sql = 'SELECT lat, lon, name FROM locations WHERE lat >= ? AND lat <= ? AND lon >= ? AND lon <= ?';
```

Whilst your query may well change dramatically following the advice above, it may still be useful to know that you can abbreviate this query using MySQL's [`BETWEEN ... AND ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator: `WHERE (lat BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (lon BETWEEN ? AND ?)`.

You might also find your code easier to maintain if you use named parameters instead of placeholders: `WHERE (lat BETWEEN :minlat AND :maxlat) AND (lon BETWEEN :minlon AND :maxlon)`.

```
$params = array( $minlat, $maxlat, $minlon, $maxlon );
```

If using named placeholders, you could use an associative array as `$params = array ( ':minlat' => $minlat, ... );`.

In either case, you could bind values or variables to your parameters separately (which is my preferred approach, as it easily enables one to run the query again with only some parameters changed): `$q->bindParam(':minlat', $minlat);` etc.

```
$q = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$q->execute( $params );
$doc = new DOMDocument();
```

Check that it succeeded: `if (!$doc) die('Unable to create DOMDocument object');`.

```
$r = $doc->createElement( "locations" );
$doc->appendChild( $r );
foreach ( $q->fetchAll() as $row) {
```

`fetchAll()` fetches the entire resultset into PHP, which could require a lot of memory if the resultset is large.  Where one merely wishes to iterate over each record in turn, it's usually better to fetch each record as required: `while ( $row = $q->fetch() )`.

```
  {
```

This brace (together with its pair below) is superfluous.

```
    $e = $doc->createElement( "location" );
    $e->setAttribute( 'name', $row['name'] );
    $e->setAttribute( 'd', $d );
```

Where is your `$d` variable declared/assigned?

```
    $r->appendChild( $e );
  }
```

As mentioned above, this brace is superfluous.

```
}
print $doc->saveXML();
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your advice! I'll make the changes! Oh, and I was getting nothing back in the browser (or on the ios device) to answer your comment above.

Comment: Hmmm...I made the changes, such as the unnessaries, removed undeclared, edited comments, etc., but my host is down...I will have to get back to you when it goes back up.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for being so helpful with those pointers and links. But I am still getting empty results on my iPhone...and empty results in the browser. I looked over the google example, and it sort-of looks like mine. So I created a duplicate of that document and made a few adjustments based on that google link, but I still get the same result. You can view those adjustments here, but I also have this php file too just in case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878590/php-not-matching-lon-and-lat-from-ios-with-a-lon-and-lat-mysql-data-entry

Comment: Sorry, this is the link to the new php file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879484/php-is-not-matching-ios-lon-and-lat-with-a-mysql-lon-and-lat-properly