# php is not matching ios lon and lat with a mysql lon and lat properly

Tags: php, mysql, ios, xml, location

I am trying to get the output of the lat and lon coordinates from ios (this is working fine), send it to php to query with MySQL and have the php send an xml document back to ios(this step is not working because it is not bringing back the mysql entry within that location), then parsing it on iOS UItableview (this is working fine too). I am trying to get this to work with XML cause I've gotten a simpler xml script running already on it. But probably due to mistakes from inexperience in php, I cannot get this php script working! What am I doing wrong in my php script? Thanks! Oh, and also, the data categories in mysql consist of "lon" and "lat" and "name" (for the name of a nearby friend or family)! AND in case anyone was wondering, this is an evolved version of an earlier script (that was also producing the same results): [php query for iOS latitude and longitude not searching for nearby mysql lat and lon with a xml output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870803/php-query-for-ios-latitude-and-longitude-not-searching-for-nearby-mysql-lat-and)

```
<?php
    define( 'LATMILES', 1 / 69 );
    define( 'LONMILES', 1 / 53 );
    if ( isset( $_GET['lat'] ) ) { $lat = (float)$_GET['lat']; }  //Recieve ios input from: NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/loc.php?lat=%g&lon=%g&radius=100&q=%@", latitude, longitude, searchBar.text?searchBar.text:@""];
    if ( isset( $_GET['lon'] ) ) { $lon = (float)$_GET['lon']; }  //Recieve ios input from: NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/loc.php?lat=%g&lon=%g&radius=100&q=%@", latitude, longitude, searchBar.text?searchBar.text:@""];
    if ( isset( $_GET['radius'] ) ) { $radius = (float)$_GET['radius']; } //Recieve ios input from: NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/loc.php?lat=%g&lon=%g&radius=100&q=%@", latitude, longitude, searchBar.text?searchBar.text:@""];
    $minlat = $lat - ( $radius * LATMILES );
    $minlon = $lon - ( $radius * LONMILES );
    $maxlat = $lat + ( $radius * LATMILES );
    $maxlon = $lon + ( $radius * LONMILES );
    $dbh = new PDO('(censored private information');
    $sql = 'SELECT lat, lon, name FROM locations WHERE lat >= ? AND lat <= ? AND lon >= ? AND lon <= ?';
    $params = array( $minlat, $maxlat, $minlon, $maxlon );
    if ( isset( $_GET['q'] ) ) {
      $sql .= " AND name LIKE ?";
      $params []= '%'.$_GET['q'].'%';
    }
    $q = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
    $q->execute( $params );
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $r = $doc->createElement( "locations" );
    $doc->appendChild( $r );
    foreach ( $q->fetchAll() as $row) {
      $dlat = ( (float)$row['lat'] - $lat ) / LATMILES;
      $dlon = ( (float)$row['lon'] - $lon ) / LONMILES;
      $d = sqrt( ( $dlat * $dlat ) + ( $dlon * $dlon ) );
      if ( $d <= $radius ) {
        $e = $doc->createElement( "location" );
        $e->setAttribute( 'lat', $row['lat'] );
        $e->setAttribute( 'lon', $row['lon'] );
        $e->setAttribute( 'name', $row['name'] );
        $r->appendChild( $e );
      }
    }
    print $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: Ummmm...did you read my question? This is a script that needs to be reposted due to changes in the execution of the script...

Comment: The system won't let me undo my close vote. Bummer. If you want to avoid being flagged, don't copy-and-paste the same text over and over and over in your questions, and try to reduce the code to the part that is relevant. Otherwise, it looks like the same question with superficial modifications. Following these suggestions might also have the side benefit of attracting more answers to your questions.

Comment: I'll keep those in mind. On another note, do you have any suggestions to fix this script? Where should I look?

Comment: Check your error log for messages. Use a debugger to step through the code to see where it's doing something you don't expect. Especially check that the SQL statement that is generated is the one you expect to be generated. Run it manually to see if you get the results you expect. You call `execute()` but don't appear to check for an error result. All that PDO code should be wrapped in a `try`/`catch` no doubt.

Comment: Thanks! In iOS, I get nothing. In the browser, I get nothing. Are there any other alternative programs that I could use to check my php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a over complicated. For a start the best solution for finding a location is to use the [Haversine_formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

I have simplified your code to use it.

```
<?php
if (isset( $_GET['lat'])){ 
    $lat = (float)$_GET['lat']; 
}  
if ( isset( $_GET['lon'])){ 
    $lon = (float)$_GET['lon']; 
}  
if ( isset( $_GET['radius'])){ 
    $radius = (float)$_GET['radius'];
} 
if ( isset( $_GET['q'])){ 
    $name = $_GET['q'];
} 

$dbh = new PDO('(censored private information');
//
$sql = "SELECT  name, lat, lon, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat) ) * cos( radians( lon ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lon) ) ) ) AS distance FROM location WHERE `name` LIKE '%s' HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
mysql_real_escape_string($lon),
mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
mysql_real_escape_string($name),
mysql_real_escape_string($radius));

$q = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$q->execute( $params );
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$r = $doc->createElement( "locations" );
$doc->appendChild( $r );
foreach ( $q->fetchAll() as $row) {
  //$dlat = ( (float)$row['lat'] - $lat ) / LATMILES;
  //$dlon = ( (float)$row['lon'] - $lon ) / LONMILES;
  //]$d = sqrt( ( $dlat * $dlat ) + ( $dlon * $dlon ) );
  //if ( $d <= $radius ) {
    $e = $doc->createElement( "location" );
    $e->setAttribute( 'lat', $row['lat'] );
    $e->setAttribute( 'lon', $row['lon'] );
    $e->setAttribute( 'name', $row['name'] );
    $r->appendChild( $e );
  //}
}
echo $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

I have commented out some of your code as I don't think it is required.

I have also changed `print $doc->saveXML();` to`echo $doc->saveXML();`

I would also try hard coding the parameters ie `$lat =55.00;` etc to ensure the required output is obtained.

The formula above i sin miles to change to km use  6371  instead of 3959

Comment: Thanks! I had hardcoded a paremeter for my script and it worked, but it wasn't working with the ios location. This, for some reason, did work with it! Thanks!!!